# grab form data in websockets - nodejs

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, websocket, pg

I try to mix websockets, nodejs server and HTML5 API

On the front-end I have

```
var formData = new FormData();  
formData.append('file', files[0]);
formData.append('case', 'test');
```

so that I can grab an image and send it with using websockets like so

```
mysoc.send(formData)
```

My question is, on nodejs 0.10.12, how can I retrieve the form data, how can I do something like

```
$case=$_POST['case'];
```

Using php I can do it, but using javascript and nodejs I am lost. I am using [the pg module](https://www.npmjs.org/package/pg) but I found no similar example.

Any help?

Thanks

Comment: can't you just send JSON/binary instead of a hard-to-unpack form chunk? you can find POST parsers, but why more it more complex than needed?

Comment: @dandavis But will JSON transfer the image file "as is" or I have to turn it to, say, BLOB?

Comment: you can send blobs directly over sockets now. i think the last common holdback was iOS5. also, Files are Blobs, so theres no conversion needed.

Comment: do you have an example? a link? thanks again

Comment: mysoc.send(files[0]); for the meta: mysoc.send(JSON.stringify(files[0]));

Comment: @dahdavis This is really cool, thanks. But I dont have a clue how to upload it, when it gets to the nodejs. In php is like `move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],"upload/" . iconv('UTF-8', 'Windows-1253', $_FILES["file"]["name"]));` but in nodejs/pg I dont know what to do...

Comment: handling it node would depend on your socket package, but it should be pre-parsed as an event argument property